# jQuery Validation - How to restrict users from entering numbers and special characters in the text field?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I know I can do this using following code. But then it does not allow me to enter hindi or marathi characters in the text field.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function( value, element ) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
        var key = value;

        if (!regex.test(key)) {
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }, "please use only alphabetic characters");
```

Basically, idea is to allow users to enter only text (excluding numbers and special characters), text could be in Marathi or hindi or english.

Answer (score 0):

Hindi/marathi char are unicodes. in that case prior to check number or special char you can check for if it unicodes entry.

if true then skip checking numbers validations.

below code snippet you can use to get length of each char:

```
function getCharByteLen(char) {

    var byteLen=0;
        var c = char.charCodeAt(0);
        byteLen += c < (1 <<  7) ? 1 :
                   c < (1 << 11) ? 2 :
                   c < (1 << 16) ? 3 :
                   c < (1 << 21) ? 4 :
                   c < (1 << 26) ? 5 :
                   c < (1 << 31) ? 6 : Number.NaN;

    return byteLen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search explicitly for special characters.

```
var regex = new RegExp("[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()0-9]+$");
```

Comment: Its also not allowing capital letters e.g ABCD. Otherwise it works properly.